# what is mysql query for below four tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have four tables.

User:

```
user_id  user_name  client_id
1          abhi       1
2          ravi       2
```

Client:

```
client_id   client_name    products
1            tom          cake, patties 
2            pet          cookie, cake
```

Products:

```
product_id  product_name
1            cake
2            cookie
3            patties
```

Report:

```
report_id   product_id 
1              1
2              3
3              2
4              1
5              3
```

If Ravi login then he only able see report like below:

```
report_id   product_id 
1               1
3               2
4               1
```

I need only MySQL Query

Comment: Split `Client` table into two. `Clients` and `Client_Products`.

Comment: your `products` column in incorrect schema, split it, to contain single value!!!

Answer (score 0):

In your "Client" table instead of saving multiple values of "product" split it and put only "product id" rather than actual product value that's why you have table "product". Your table "client" is not in [First normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). So if possible, change the structure of table

Comment: but i don't want to change design or structure

Comment: Did you create the table in MySQL, because it is almost impossible to create and insert data into a table without 1NF. So best option is to change the structure.

Comment: ill try to change structure.

Comment: Just change the structure and then you can use mysql nested Select query to retrieve the information you want. If you think I answered your question just tick "Correct Answer"

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Simemon's answer, you need to normalize your DB tables.

Then also if you want to go with this table structure only, you can try this.

```
select * from reports where product_id in (select product_id from products where product_name in (select products from clients where client_id = (select client_id from users where username = 'ravi' limit 1)))
```

I have not tested this. let me know if it gives any error, I will check it.